# How do I add offsets to addresses stored in a raw pointer?

Tags: rust, raw-pointer

My goal is to store addresses and add offsets.  As an example I have something like this:

```
let base_addr = 0x0112A160 as *mut u32;
```

Now I want to store a second address which is `base_addr + offset`

I've tried some things but everything I've tried brings the program to crash with (exit code: 0xc0000005, STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION) or some other problems

Example of what I've tried:

```
let new_address: u32 = *base_addr + 0xF8;
let new_address = base_addr + 0xF8 as *mut 32;
```

Can anyone explain to me how something like this is done correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Use the method:

```rust
let base_addr = 0x0112A160 as *mut u32;
let new_address = unsafe { base_addr.offset(0xF8) };
```

or if you want to offset in bytes and can use nightly

```rust
#![feature(pointer_byte_offsets)] // at top of file
let new_address = unsafe { base_addr.byte_offset(0xF8) };
```

Comment: `byte_offset`, probably.

Comment: @cafce25 Quite probable. I frequently find that I need to apply an offset based on the position in memory in bytes. For example, a data header will usually not be stored in an array and its position will often be recorded as the offset from the buffer start. In these situations the initial pointer frequently looks like `*mut DataBuffer` so it would be easy to accidentally perform undefined behavior with `buffer.offset(0xF8) as *mut FooData`. If the goal is to mimic pointer arithmetic in C, then this may be desirable. However, I still think it should be noted.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that if the asker's code more closely reflects a byte offset.

Comment: First thanks for the answers. byte_offset did work just how I needed it. I'm kinda new to rust and I'm right now learning a bit about working with windows API(reading and writing memory). I did see some c++ code examples where the same was done but with uintptr_t. in the c++ code it was done with addr1 + addr2 or offset. my goal was to replicate this behavior for my rust code.

Comment: The real answer would probably be use a `#[repr(C)]` struct together with `MaybeUninit` and `as_ptr()` in that case.